# Can Highchart maps[Highmaps] be integrated on top of Google maps or any other satellite maps?

Tags: highcharts, mapping, gis

I would like get highmap marker clusters to be plotted onto Google maps. **Could that be possible to get highchart map points on top of any satellite maps?**

Comment: It is not possible to integrate Highcharts features with the google maps.